# How to set a value of 1 and 0 to output from Match command in Neo4j using GDS library?

Tags: neo4j, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter Notebook to run cypher queries via py2neo and pygds libraries. I can run the cypher queries via neo4j browser too.

This command gives me the counts:

```
gds.run_cypher('MATCH u=(p:Nodelabel1 {property1: "Nodelabel2"})-[r:relationship1]->WHERE r.integer > 10 RETURN Count (u)')
```

Output is:

```
|  | Count (u) |
|0 | 526       |
```

I want to set these counts as 1's and the ones which are not in this count as 0's i:e which are r.integer < 10, under Nodelabel1 with a new variable/property name ofcourse.

I tried it using the two rows method Nathan Smith has shown below. I got the counts for the two categories too. But when I try

```
gds.run_cypher('MATCH(u:Nodelabel1) RETURN u.category AS category, count(u) AS cnt')
```

I get:

```
|  | category | cnt
|0 | None     | 120711
```

I expect to get:

```
|  | category                     | cnt
|0 | Less than or equal to 10     | 20733
|1 | Greater than 10              | 526
```

Comment: You can do a sub query call in your cypher query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the answer in two rows, do it this way:

```
gds.run_cypher("""
MATCH (p:Nodelabel1 {property1: "Nodelabel2"})-[r:relationship1]->() 
RETURN 
CASE WHEN r.integer > 10 THEN "Greater than 10" 
    ELSE "Less than or equal to 10" END AS category, 
Count (*) AS count
""")
```

If you want the answer in two columns, do it this way:

```
gds.run_cypher("""
MATCH (p:Nodelabel1 {property1: "Nodelabel2"})-[r:relationship1]->() 
WITH 
SUM(CASE WHEN r.integer > 10 THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 END) AS greaterThanTen, 
Count (*) AS total
RETURN greaterThanTen, total - greaterThanTen AS lessThanOrEqualToTen
""")
```

Comment: I tried it using the two rows method you showed. I got the counts for the two categories too. But when I try 
gds.run_cypher('MATCH(u:Nodelabel1) RETURN u.category AS category, count(u) AS cnt')


I get: 

    category   count
0  None        120711 

I expect to get: 

    category                                     count
0  Less than or equal to 10         20733
1   Greater than 10                        526

Comment: That is because the "category" value is calculated in query. It is not stored as a property on the nodes. If you wanted to update the Nodelabel1 nodes with the category, you could run gds.run_cypher("""MATCH (p:Nodelabel1 {property1: "Nodelabel2"})-[r:relationship1]->() 
SET p.category =  
CASE WHEN r.integer > 10 THEN "Greater than 10" 
    ELSE "Less than or equal to 10" END AS category""")

Comment: I get the invalid input 'S': expected 'n/N' error with the above command.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Try this. gds.run_cypher("""MATCH (p:Nodelabel1 {property1: "Nodelabel2"})-[r:relationship1]->() SET p.category = CASE WHEN r.integer > 10 THEN "Greater than 10" ELSE "Less than or equal to 10" END""")

Comment: Sorry, it did not work. I tried gds.run_cypher("""
MATCH (p:Nodelabel1 {property1: "Nodelabel2"})-[r:relationship1]->() 
SET p.category = 
CASE WHEN r.integer > 10 THEN '1' 
    ELSE '0' END
"""). and gds.run_cypher('MATCH(u:Nodelabel1) RETURN u.category AS category, count(u) AS cnt').  I get three catgeories, None, 0 and 1 with wrong counts.

Comment: The first cypher statement updates only the nodes that have the label Nodelabel1 and match the rest of the pattern. They must have a property1 value equal to "Nodelabel2" and they at least one outbound relationship of type "relationship1". Based on your "None" results, there are some Nodelabel1 nodes in your graph that don't match the pattern. I also think that you have some Nodelabel1 nodes that match the pattern more than once, with different values of r.integer associated. That could make the counts of category 1 and category 0 to come out differently than you expect.